# Predict churn in a range of time after observation window is finished

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, classification, moving-window, churn

I'm building a churn model. Each user's historic data (observation window) is a constant period, but each observation window contains different dates.

For example the next figure:

[image: Dynamic Timeline for observation window]

Let's say, that the observation window contains the last month data before the user's last action.

The user's last action detriments the window dates. If it is a churner it will be the churn activity date, otherwise, it will be the non-churner's last transaction date.

In this way I limit my model to a yes/no answer for the next question: will the user leave immediately after the observation widow is finished?

I can create a gap between the observation window and the last action, it is called performance window. For example, I decide that the performance window is two weeks. Like in the next example:
[image: An example for performance window]

Also in this case,  the model will answer the next question: does a user churn 14 days after his last action?

What can I do if want that the model will answer the next question: does a user churn during the next 14 days after his last action? For example, if the user churns  0 days, or 1 day, or .... or 13 days, or 14 days, after his last action the model returns 1, else it returns 0.

*The first figure retrieved from Machine learning techniques for customer churn prediction in banking environments [(Avon, 2016)](http://tesi.cab.unipd.it/53212/)